# Active Record: Find collection based on sum of two associated tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to find the collection of 'underpaid' events in our system. We are running Rails 3.2 using a Postgres database.

The data structure is as follows.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges
  has_many :transactions
end

class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Underpaid events are defined as those where the total charges are greater than total transactions.

```
sum(charges.total) > sum(transactions.total)
```

My SQL skills are poor and I have been trying to execute this using ActiveRecord. This is my latest attempt but it is not bringing back the right collection. In particular it seems to include fully paid events where there was more than one transaction.

```
Event.joins(:charges,:transactions).group('charges.event_id, transactions.event_id').having("sum(charges.total) > sum(transactions.total)")
```

Is it possible to achieve this in ActiveRecord and if so, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think that in SQL it should be like that

```
select * from events where 
(select sum(charges.total) from charges where charges.event_id = events.id) > 
(select sum(transactions.total) from transactions where 
transactions.event_id = events.id)
```

so for now you can build scope like

```
scope :unpaid, find_by_sql("select * from events where 
(select sum(charges.total) from charges where charges.event_id = events.id) > 
(select sum(transactions.total) from transactions where 
transactions.event_id = events.id)")
```

I hope it will help!